# Delete observations by a range in a variable in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that that I want to subset based on the number of months each ID has, where an ID has multiple observations. I only want to keep the observations where a unique ID has a range from 1 - 7 in the variable month. For example, in the table below the only ID's I want to keep are 2 and 4. I have multiple ID's in my original data that are not 2 or 4, so I can't just type '''if is not ((ID = 2) or (ID = 4)) then delete'''.
I've tried using proc iml, the lag function, and nested if then statements, but I can't seem to get my code to run the way I want it to. If there is a simpler way that I'm overlooking, please point me in the right direction.

| ID | Month |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |

Here are some codes I've tried:

```
data work.want;
    set work.have;
    if first.month < 7
    then do;
        if id = lag(id)
        then delete;
    end;
    by descending id;
run;
```

```
proc iml;
use work.have;
list all where ((1 <= month <= 7) & (account_id = lag(account_id)));
close work.have;
```

```
data work.want;
    set work.have;
    if (first.month < 7) and (account_id = lag(account_id))
    then month_total = month_total+lag(month);
    by descending id;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be ways to simplify this, but based on what you've posted, this is likely the easiest solution for you to understand and modify.

```
data have;
infile cards dlm='09'x;
input ID    Month;
cards;
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
2   4
2   5
2   6
2   7
3   1
3   2
4   1
4   2
4   3
4   4
4   5
4   6
4   7
;;;;;
run;

data IDS_keep;
set have;
by ID;

retain flag 0;

*for each new id, reset counters and flags;
if first.id then do; counter=0; flag=0; end;
*increment counter and check it matches month value;
counter+1;
*if not, set flag to 1;
if counter ne month then flag=1;

*if last month and last id and flag not flipped then ID is complete;
if month=7 and last.id and flag=0 then output;

*commented out, but uncomment for more efficient processing;
*keep id;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
select * from have
where id in (select ID from IDS_keep);
quit;
```